# Realm - ordered items?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, realm

I want to store my items in Realm in an ordered array, and was wondering if there was any support for this, or any way to do this? For instance, I could have an index value, but if I moved an item further up, I'd then be required to change the values of each item in between.

Answer (score 1):

RLMArray is ordered container so you can just store your items there. It also has a method for [inserting at index](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.90.5/api/Classes/RLMArray.html#//api/name/insertObject:atIndex:)